# List with exceptions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have created a table from a list element in my HTML with JavaScript, and it works really well, but not all my documents have citations to fetch. How can I make it that the code only runs if there is an ELEMENT element found.

The code has to be that if this part isn't found nothing happens and the function continues. So if there is no ELEMENT1 in the document it will still look for ELEMENT2. Atm it gives me an error and stopps after it cant find ELEMENT1.

```
const ELEMENT =  Array.from(document.getElementById('ID').getElementsByTagName('li'));
```

Full code for the table

```
function myFunction{

            const ELEMENT1 =  Array.from(document.getElementById('ID').getElementsByTagName('li'));
            const nonPatCit_tbody = document.querySelector('#table tbody');

            ELEMENT1 .forEach(
                (ELEMENT1 ) => {
                    // a table row for each element 
                    const tr = nonPatCit_tbody.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
                   
                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = Array.from(nonPatCit.querySelectorAll('name'))
                            .map((name) => name.textContent)
                            .join(', ');
                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = nonPatCit.querySelector('atl')?.textContent || '';

                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = nonPatCit.querySelector('sertitle')?.textContent || '';

                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = nonPatCit.querySelector('sdate')?.textContent || '';
                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = nonPatCit.querySelector('vid')?.textContent || '';

                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = nonPatCit.querySelector('ino')?.textContent || '';

                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = nonPatCit.querySelector('ppf')?.textContent || '';
                    
                    // multiple authors, map nodes to strings and join them
                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = Array.from(nonPatCit.querySelectorAll('crossref'))
                            .map((crossref) => crossref.textContent)
                            .join(', ');
                }
            )

  const ELEMENT2 =  Array.from(document.getElementById('ID').getElementsByTagName('li'));
            const nonPatCit_tbody2 = document.querySelector('#table tbody');

            ELEMENT2 .forEach(
                (ELEMENT2 ) => {
                    // a table row for each element 
                    const tr = nonPatCit_tbody2.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
                   
                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = Array.from(ELEMENT2.querySelectorAll('name'))
                            .map((name) => name.textContent)
                            .join(', ');
                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = ELEMENT2 .querySelector('atl')?.textContent || '';

                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = ELEMENT2 .querySelector('sertitle')?.textContent || '';

                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = ELEMENT2 .querySelector('sdate')?.textContent || '';
                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = ELEMENT2 .querySelector('vid')?.textContent || '';

                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = ELEMENT2 .querySelector('ino')?.textContent || '';

                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = ELEMENT2 .querySelector('ppf')?.textContent || '';
                    
                    // multiple authors, map nodes to strings and join them
                    tr
                        .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
                        .textContent = Array.from(ELEMENT2 .querySelectorAll('crossref'))
                            .map((crossref) => crossref.textContent)
                            .join(', ');
                }
            )
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but you'll find it easier if you don't reuse variable names to mean different things, `element.foreach((element) =>` it's not possible to access the outer `element` variable - when you have a collection/array/list etc, use plural, so `const elements = Array.from` then `elements.foreach((element) =>` and it's much clearer inside the forEach what `element` is referring to and you can still access the outer `elements` if needed.

Comment: Your code already does what (it appears) you're asking.   `var elements = []; elements.forEach((element) => console.log(element))` will output nothing.  If there's nothing in the array, the forEach will have no iterations.

Comment: I have tried to clarify the issue. Its not about the tds and the elements inside the table. That works fine. Its about that if it cannot find the ELEMENT1 it gives an error and doesnt look for the element2 and element3 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no element were found, the empty array is returned and stored in `ELEMENT`, which the [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method simply ignores:

```
const ELEMENT = Array.from(document.getElementById('ID')?.getElementsByTagName('li') ?? Array())
```

Read more:

- [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
- [Array()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array)

Of course, I also prefer to use plural nouns to define collections — e.g., `ELEMENTS` instead of `ELEMENT`.